# Does an html/php/asp etc. file work properly without tags to group them in a browser?

Tags: php, html

Here's what I mean. Let's say I have a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Something</title>
        </head>

        <body>
            <h1>Something here</h1>
            <p>Something there</p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

When I'm done with it I'd want to jumble everything into a huge hulk like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Something</title></head><body><h1>Something here</h1><p>Something there</p></body></html>
```

Will it affect the performance or ruin the page?

I'm asking this because I tried doing it in a *php* file for the *php* code and It gave me an error. It didn't work. I was looking at Google's index and everything's stuffed like that.

Comment: Yes, it's valid html code. Maybe you had some comments in PHP file, because you could create single-line file. Check minified JS/css files also.
Minifying html will not increase page performance, but it will take less time for browser to download resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will work, HTML does not need to use any line breaks in order for the code to work. Your assumptions are correct. No performance will be affected.